# In which sense is u a solution for (1) on $ \Omega=B_1(0) $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider $$ \begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
     -\Delta{\omega}=f \ on \ \Omega  \\
       \ \ \ \ \ \omega=0 \ on \ \partial\Omega
   \end{cases} \ \ \ \ \   \ (1)\end{equation}  $$
*Definition 1 :* $$ Let\ \  u\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)\ \  such\ \ that \\
\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u*\nabla\phi-f\phi)dx=0 \ \ for \ \ all \ \ \phi\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)\ , $$
 $$ then \ \  u \ \ is \ \ called \ \ a \ \  weak \ \ solution \ \ for \ \ (1) \ \ on \ \  \Omega \ .$$ 
 $$ \\ $$
*Definition 2 :*$$ Let\ \  u\in C_0(\overline \Omega)\ \  such\ \ that \\
\int_{\Omega}(- u*\Delta\phi-f\phi)dx=0 \ \ for \ \ all \ \ \phi\in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega) \ ,$$ 
 $$ then \ \  u \ \ is \ \ called \ \ a \ \  distributional \    \ solution \ \ for \ \ (1) \ \ on \ \  \Omega \ .$$ 
$$ \\ $$
 I'm not really sure , but I think u is a distributional solution for (1) . Using a few times partial Integration and keeping in mind that the integral on the boundary disappears  and that u is   continuously differentiable  I get the following :
$$ -\int_{B_1(0)}u\Delta\phi dx=-\int_{\partial B_1(0)}u\nabla\phi\nu d\sigma_x+\int_{B_1(0)}\nabla u \nabla \phi dx\\
=\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\nabla u \phi\nu d\sigma_x-\int_{B_1(0)}\Delta u\phi dx=-\int_{B_1(0)}\Delta u\phi dx=\int_{B_1(0)}f\phi dx . $$
I forgot something to mention $$ u(x_1,x_2)= x_1x_2(1-\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}) , where \ \ (x_1,x_2)\in \overline{B_1(0)}\subset \mathbb{R^2}$$

Comment: I did a quick calculation, and it appears that $u\in W^{1,2}_0$ for the $u$ that you provided. This may mean it is a weak solution. Someone may need to confirm, though.

Comment: I don't really understand what I've to do if $$ u \in W^{1,2}_0 $$ . Well then it follows that $$ u \in B_1(0)\{0} $$ is a distributional solution for (1) .

Comment: I don't really understand what I've to do if $$ u \in W^{1,2}_0 $$ . In fact I computed that u is in  $$  W^{3,p}(B_1(0)) \cap W^{4,1}(B_1(0))  $$ .

Comment: Can someone explain me how I can show that u is a distributional solution for  (1) on $$ B_1(0)\diagdown (0,0) $$ ? I know that  $$ u\in C^{\infty}(B_1(0)\diagdown(0,0)) $$ .